# What is wrong with this code PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code :

```
  <div class="gigel"><?php
    // In case there is opening and closing shortcode.
    echo do_shortcode('[woocs show_flags=1 width='300px' flag_position='right']');
    ?></div>
```

This is shortcode:

```
[woocs show_flags=1 width='300px' flag_position='right']
```

This is the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '300' (T_LNUMBER) in /home/dacproie/public_html/test2/wp/wp-content/themes/mix/header.php on line 189
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

just change below code with

```
<div class="gigel"><?php
// In case there is opening and closing shortcode.
echo do_shortcode("[woocs show_flags=1 width='300px' flag_position='right']");
?></div>
```

i hope this is working for you.

Comment: You're right, of course, but you may want to explain why for the OP as well.

Answer (score 0):

please, try to clean your code

```
<?php
    $forHtml = do_shortcode("[woocs show_flags=1 width='300px' flag_position='right']");
?>

<!-- separate your layers -->

<div class="gigel"><?php
    <?php print ("%s", $forHtml); ?>
?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use double quotes when you have to use `do_shortcode()` function.

So use of double quotes instead of single quotes fix your problem and you need to modify it as like :

```
<div class="gigel">
 <?php
   echo do_shortcode("[woocs show_flags=1 width='300px' flag_position='right']"); 
  ?>
</div>
```